# XSLT sorting on multiple attributes/element

Tags: xslt

I am trying to sort on multiple attributes/elements. Sorting on @status and cci:ArtifactLocation works fine, however the same technique does not sort on cci:ArtifactLocation/@line attribute. I used XMLSpy 2014 and saxon9he.jar for testing with the same result. Do you know what may be wrong?

1. input XML is the following:

   ```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <ValidatorResult xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/soa/fp/governance/auditor">
   <Header>
     <SourceDirectory>file:/ade/ranchand_dte8052/oracle/work/CodeComplianceInspectorLrg/testData/AIADemo/</SourceDirectory>
     <SourceDirectoryMask>${inputDir}</SourceDirectoryMask>
     <DisplayLabel>AIADemo</DisplayLabel>
     <AssertionCatalog>AssertionCatalog-WS-I_12.1.3.0.0.xml</AssertionCatalog>
     <PoliciesFile>Policies-WS-I_12.1.3.0.0.xml</PoliciesFile>
     <Policy>Reusability Standards</Policy>
     <DateTime>AIA DEMO DATE OF EXECUTION</DateTime>
     <Version>AIA Build</Version>
   </Header>
   <PolicyResult name="Reusability Standards" total="1" failed="1" success="0" notExecuted="0">
     <AssertionResult priority="2" name="NoLocalSchemasInBPELCheck" category="Reusability Standards" failed="32" total="119" success="87">
       <Message>BPEL Process folder should not contain any schema files. All Utility schema should be accessed from a web server.</Message>
       <Result>Fail</Result>
       <ExecutionDetails>
           <Composite name="SamplesSyncCustomerPartyListEBF" version="1.0" success="2" failed="1">
     <Execution status="1">
               <ArtifactLocation>${inputDir}3.xTestData/EBFTargetNameSpacesCheck/SamplesSyncCustomerPartyListEBF/</ArtifactLocation>
             </Execution>
             <Execution status="0">
               <ArtifactLocation>${inputDir}3.xTestData/AIAServiceConfigFileForEBFExistsCheck/SamplesSyncCustomerPartyListEBF/</ArtifactLocation>
             </Execution>
             <Execution status="1">
               <ArtifactLocation>${inputDir}3.xTestData/wsdlRuntimeLocationExistForPlinkInEBFCheck/SamplesSyncCustomerPartyListEBF/</ArtifactLocation>
             </Execution>
           </Composite>
           <Composite name="AIADemoCreateShipmentRequestBatchProvABCSImpl" version="1.0" success="1" failed="0">
             <Execution status="1">
               <ArtifactLocation>${inputDir}samples/AIADemo/ProviderABCS/AIADemoCreateShipmentRequestBatchProvABCSImpl/</ArtifactLocation>
             </Execution>
           </Composite>
           <Composite name="MatchAccountSiebelReqABCSImpl" version="1.0" success="1" failed="0">
             <Execution status="1">
               <ArtifactLocation>${inputDir}Siebel/RequesterABCS/MatchAccountSiebelReqABCSImpl/</ArtifactLocation>
             </Execution>
           </Composite>
           <Composite name="CheckATPSalesOrderSiebelFusionDOOABF" version="1.0" success="9" failed="2">
             <Execution status="1">
               <ArtifactLocation line="400" col="46">${inputDir}ApplicationBusinessFlow/CheckATPSalesOrderSiebelFusionDOOABF/CheckATPSalesOrderSiebelFusionDOOABF.bpel</ArtifactLocation>
             </Execution>
     <Execution status="1">
       <ArtifactLocation line="131" col="46">${inputDir}ApplicationBusinessFlow/CheckATPSalesOrderSiebelFusionDOOABF/CheckATPSalesOrderSiebelFusionDOOABF.bpel</ArtifactLocation>
             </Execution>
             <Execution status="1">
               <ArtifactLocation line="159" col="54">${inputDir}ApplicationBusinessFlow/CheckATPSalesOrderSiebelFusionDOOABF/CheckATPSalesOrderSiebelFusionDOOABF.bpel</ArtifactLocation>
             </Execution>
             <Execution status="1">
               <ArtifactLocation line="186" col="45">${inputDir}ApplicationBusinessFlow/CheckATPSalesOrderSiebelFusionDOOABF/CheckATPSalesOrderSiebelFusionDOOABF.bpel</ArtifactLocation>
             </Execution>
             <Execution status="1">
               <ArtifactLocation line="221" col="33">${inputDir}ApplicationBusinessFlow/CheckATPSalesOrderSiebelFusionDOOABF/CheckATPSalesOrderSiebelFusionDOOABF.bpel</ArtifactLocation>
             </Execution>
             <Execution status="0">
               <ArtifactLocation line="238" col="82">${inputDir}ApplicationBusinessFlow/CheckATPSalesOrderSiebelFusionDOOABF/CheckATPSalesOrderSiebelFusionDOOABF.bpel</ArtifactLocation>
             </Execution>
             <Execution status="1">
               <ArtifactLocation line="249" col="43">${inputDir}ApplicationBusinessFlow/CheckATPSalesOrderSiebelFusionDOOABF/CheckATPSalesOrderSiebelFusionDOOABF.bpel</ArtifactLocation>
             </Execution>
             <Execution status="1">
               <ArtifactLocation line="264" col="56">${inputDir}ApplicationBusinessFlow/CheckATPSalesOrderSiebelFusionDOOABF/CheckATPSalesOrderSiebelFusionDOOABF.bpel</ArtifactLocation>
             </Execution>
             <Execution status="0">
               <ArtifactLocation line="345" col="50">${inputDir}ApplicationBusinessFlow/CheckATPSalesOrderSiebelFusionDOOABF/CheckATPSalesOrderSiebelFusionDOOABF.bpel</ArtifactLocation>
             </Execution>
             <Execution status="1">
               <ArtifactLocation line="376" col="39">${inputDir}ApplicationBusinessFlow/CheckATPSalesOrderSiebelFusionDOOABF/CheckATPSalesOrderSiebelFusionDOOABF.bpel</ArtifactLocation>
             </Execution>
             <Execution status="1">
               <ArtifactLocation line="104" col="99">${inputDir}ApplicationBusinessFlow/CheckATPSalesOrderSiebelFusionDOOABF/CheckATPSalesOrderSiebelFusionDOOABF.bpel</ArtifactLocation>
             </Execution>
           </Composite>
       </ExecutionDetails>
     </AssertionResult>
   </PolicyResult>
   ```

XSLT transformation is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:cci="http://www.oracle.com/soa/fp/governance/auditor" exclude-result-prefixes="cci">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="cci:ExecutionDetails">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="cci:Composite">
                <xsl:sort select="@name" lang="en" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>             
            </xsl:apply-templates>          
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="cci:Composite">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="version"><xsl:value-of select="@version"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="success"><xsl:value-of select="@success"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="failed"><xsl:value-of select="@failed"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not(cci:Composite/cci:ArtifactLocation/@line)">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="cci:Execution">
                        <xsl:sort select="@status" data-type="number"/>                     
                        <xsl:sort select="cci:ArtifactLocation" lang="en" case-order="lower-first" order="ascending"/>                      
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>                 
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="cci:Execution">
                        <xsl:sort select="@status" data-type="number"/>
                        <xsl:sort select="cci:ArtifactLocation" lang="en" case-order="lower-first" order="ascending"/>
                        <xsl:sort select="cci:ArtifactLocation/@line" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>                                            
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="cci:Execution">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="status"><xsl:value-of select="@status"/></xsl:attribute>               
            <xsl:apply-templates select="cci:ArtifactLocation"/>        
        </xsl:copy>     
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="cci:ArtifactLocation">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For the benefit of the public, here's the answer to this question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:cci="http://www.oracle.com/soa/fp/governance/auditor" exclude-result-prefixes="cci">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="cci:ExecutionDetails">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="cci:Composite">
                <xsl:sort select="@name" lang="en" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="cci:Composite">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="version"><xsl:value-of select="@version"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="success"><xsl:value-of select="@success"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="failed"><xsl:value-of select="@failed"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="cci:Execution">
                <xsl:sort select="@status" data-type="number"/>
                <xsl:sort select="cci:ArtifactLocation" lang="en" case-order="lower-first" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:sort select="cci:ArtifactLocation/@line" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="cci:Execution">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="status"><xsl:value-of select="@status"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="cci:ArtifactLocation"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="cci:ArtifactLocation">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT, the test  in:

```
<xsl:when test="not(cci:Composite/cci:ArtifactLocation/@line)">
```

will always return true, because this is done from the context of `cci:Composite`, therefore the (relative) path `cci:Composite/cci:ArtifactLocation/@line` selects nothing. So you are not really sorting by `cci:ArtifactLocation/@line` after all.

Comment: any suggestions on how to improve?

Comment: @vg600 Why do you need this condition at all? If the attribute is not there, the sort will do nothing.

Comment: you are right. Removed the condition and everything started working. Thank you for your help.